# How to stream a webGL canvas with WebRTC?

Tags: three.js, webgl, webrtc

I have an webGL canvas rendering an 3D hologram image using Three.js and I want to stream it as a video to another pc.

I already tried the code below and didn't work.

```
  var gl = renderer.getContext();       //get webGl context 
  var canvas = gl.canvas;               //get gl's canvas 

  var video = document.querySelector('video');
  var stream = canvas.captureStream();
  video.srcObject = stream;
```

Is it possible to stream and webGl canvas with WebRTC?

Answer (score 3):

this is not yet fully supported in Chrome (Firefox should work since 43), you need "Experimental Web Platform features" in chrome://flags. 
See [this demo](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/capture/canvas-pc/) for a classical teapot example.

Comment: Exactly. I based my code my on this teapot without the peer connection [link here](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/tree/gh-pages/src/content/capture/canvas-video). I don't know if I have to do more than that, but on the main.js it only has the code that I wrote and an call for the main method of demo.js, which I don't undestand what it does.

Comment: Oh my god! My code works just fine.For some reason the video was beeing place underneath the canvas, so I was thinking that it was not working.

Thanks for trying to help.